# How to get the OAuth token from within android app?

Tags: android, google-api, google-oauth

I have register my app and prepared my link to generate OAuth 2.0 for users of my apps.

Which way works for android?

Listening to:
`localhost:portNUmber` or
returning the token in a web page's title?

And how to create a button to request this authentication from the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking on how to obtain an access token to access Google API's for user data protected by OAuth2 authorization, you probably want to read how to use the GoogleAuthUtil class to request 'oauth2:' tokens. Two good sources are:

https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html

and

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/09/google-play-services-and-oauth-identity.html

If you are looking for a token to authenticate your app + signed-in google user back to your home server, you should also look into GoogleAuthUtil, but request an 'audience:' token:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html